# modify a copy of a component without affecting the original Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm using drag and drop functionality to copy a component but every time i modify the copied component it changes the original, here's my code:

```
<template>


<header class="nav-h">
    <NavBar msg="You did it!" />
  </header>
  <div class="w-full h-94 flex justify-between">
    <SideBar />
    <div class="dropzone" @drop="onDrop" @dragover.prevent>
      <ul>
      <li v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="index">
        <!-- Render each component in the list -->
        <component :is="component"></component>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <RightSideBar />
    <RouterView />
  </div>
</template>
```

And here's my  logic:

```
data() {
    return {
      handleParentDrop: false,
      
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    ...mapWritableState(useComponentStore, ["components", "emptyComponent"]),
  },

  methods:{
    onDrop(event) {
      console.log(event);
      const data = event.dataTransfer.getData('componentType')
      if (event.target.className !== "main" && !event.target.classList.contains("custom")) {
        this.components.add(data)
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      else{
        this.emptyComponent.push(data)
        console.log(this.emptyComponent);
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    },
  },

}
```

the problem is that i'm looping over component names which are Strings, so i can clone them, is there a way to loop over components themselves not the strings?